# SQL Self Join with Criteria

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with a list of dates that I would like to join together whilst adding in a new column. I've pasted an example below:

```
    Date
    03/03/2014
    03/03/2014
    03/03/2014
    04/03/2014
    04/03/2014
    04/03/2014
    04/03/2014
```

That is the first table, however I would like to self join it so it appears like this:

```
    Index_Date  Date
    03/03/2014  03/03/2014
    03/03/2014  03/03/2014
    03/03/2014  03/03/2014
    04/03/2014  03/03/2014
    04/03/2014  03/03/2014
    04/03/2014  03/03/2014
    04/03/2014  04/03/2014
    04/03/2014  04/03/2014
    04/03/2014  04/03/2014
    04/03/2014  04/03/2014
```

This is just an example of the data, but would appreciate any help in being able to do this! If you need any further in then please let me know.

Thanks, Sam

Here is some test code that I've put together:

```
    CREATE TABLE #DATES (Date VARCHAR (8))

    INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ('20140303')
    INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ('20140303')
    INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ('20140303')
    INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ('20140304')
    INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ('20140304')
    INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ('20140304')
    INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ('20140304')

    SELECT
         T1.Date AS T1Date
,T2.Date AS T2Date
    FROM
 #DATES AS T1
        INNER JOIN #DATES AS T2 
        ON T1.Date = T2.Date
```

The final output should be the 10 rows as shown above.

Comment: What are the join criteria?

Comment: I want it to join so that everything that is <= '03/03/2014' is selected (3 records) and then everything that is <= '04/04/2014' is select (7 records) which gives you a total of 10 records. These dates are held in another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
  dd.Date as T1Date,
  d.Date as T2Date
from
      (select distinct Date from Dates) as dd 
  left join Dates as d on d.Date <= dd.Date
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4136c/6

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you join a table to itself

```
SELECT T1.Date as T1Date, T2.Date as T2Date
    FROM FooBar T1
    INNER JOIN FooBar T2 ON T1.Date = T2.Date
```

Updated based on your additional information you need a union rather than a self join:

```
DECLARE @firstDate DATETIME
DECLARE @secondDate DATETIME
SET @firstDate = '2014-03-03'
SET @secondDate = '2014-03-04'

SELECT @firstDate as Index_Date, Date FROM @Dates
       WHERE Date <= @firstDate
 UNION
SELECT @secondDate as Index_date, Date FROM @Dates
       WHERE Date <= @secondDate
```

The two date parameters can easily be loaded from another table  if required.

This should also also give you what you want *without* the UNION:

```
SELECT ID.Index_Date, D.Date
     FROM IndexDateTable ID
    INNER JOIN Dates D ON D.Date <= ID.Index_Date
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it without a UNION, is that possible!? As there are quite a lot of dates! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I must be missing something - how many tables with dates are there? You mention in a comment above "these dates are held in another table" so is there a table that provides the dates for the filter criteria if so how many records are there?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly - the idea is that throughout the month the table will grow and the data will need to append to the previous day. So the dates table is essentially a DISTINCT list of the dates in the first table.

Comment: The 01/03/2014 wants all records that are <= 01/03/2014. The 02/03/2014 wants all records that are <= 02/03/2014. The 03/03/2014 wants all records that are <= 03/03/2014. etc

Comment: Ok updated answer based on your having 2 tables IndexDateTable and Dates table